# On form submitting, admin-ajax.php shows status as pending

Tags: ajax

On form submitting, `admin-ajax.php` shows status as pending and after some time it shows 404 error but the form is submitted on backend and the confirmation mail is also sent.

Also, When form is submitted it doesn't redirect to the next page as the status shows pending. This problem is only occurring  on the live server but when the same is done on local platform, status shows 200 i.e. OK and also redirects to the next page. This issue comes on live server automatically few days earlier.

[image: On inspecting the page, in Network section admin-ajax.php shows status as pending and after some time it shows 404 error.]

Comment: can you add the code where you make the ajax call, and the code that registers the hook for that ajax call?

Comment: Is this form being submitted via javascript? I noticed there's no code in your question can you include the problematic code? Also have you considered using a REST API endpoint? It's much easier to write and use, gives real error messages rather than cryptic failures, and it's significantly easier to secure ( Admin AJAX makes you write all the security yourself )